# Question about Save to SD card

Tags: android

I have a few apps that are getting larger as I improve functionality. I have had a few request to enable the ability to save the apps to the SD card.

I want to keep my apps available to early versions of Android. Can someone tell me what code I need to add that allows save to SD without increasing my min SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to target at least API version 8 (Froyo) using android:targetSdkVersion in the uses-sdk section of your manifest. Then you should also define android:installLocation in the manifest to either "preferExternal" or "auto" to enable install to SD. For backwards compatibility you can set android:minSdkVersion to allow your app to be installed on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: Does this look right?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">



<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

Comment: I guess not...I am doing something wrong. I am still getting error in Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure you switch your application build target over to API 8 in Eclipse or it will moan about the installLocation being invalid markup. Your XML looks correct.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:targetSdkVersion` to indicate which API level you're targeting. Then you need to use `android:minSdkVersion` to declare the minimum API level, where the phones at this level will ignore higher unknown attributes in the manifest file and then you're free to use which feature you want (e.g. SD card feature). What's important is that your **code** must target the `android:minSdkVersion` in order to get your application running on these devices.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) for more information, especially the *Backward Compatibility* section.

Comment: hmmm...I have read the Backward compatibility section but it just confused me. They need to write that stuff for retards like me.

Comment: @Stephen McClendon: What's your biggest concern about using this feature?

Comment: Here is a cut from my Manifest file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

and.....


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />


The help sections says to use something like: 

android:installLocation attribute with a value of "auto"


Its seems that if I target one sdk then I might run into problems.

Comment: I basically want to enable save to SD card for versions of Android that allow it and still enable early versions of Android to see me app in the market.

Comment: @Stephen McClendon: Make your project target Android 2.2 level, set your `minSdkVersion` to your specific need and use `targetSdk` to target the project target. Then should users still see your target in Market.

Comment: It seems like the android:installLocation is ignored by older versions then 8. You do not need anything else then setting the target to 8.